# Generate all combinations of nucleotide k-mers between range(i, j)

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, bioinformatics, python-itertools

I need to generate a list of all possible nucleotide combination of length between 5-15.

```
nucleotides = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
```

Expected results:

```
AAAAA
AAAAT
AAAAC
AAAAG
AAATA
AAATT
...
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAT
etc.
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(5,16):
    for j in itertools.permutations(nucleotides, i):
        print j
```

But this doesn't work if `len(nucleotides) < i`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find all the combinations, you should use [`.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as [`.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) will not produce repeated nucleotides like `AAAAA` or `AATGC` anyway. Try this:

```
for i in range(5, 16):
    combinations = itertools.product(*itertools.repeat(nucleotides, i))
    for j in combinations:
        print(j)
```

Update: As @JaredGoguen mentioned, the `repeat` argument can also be used here:

```
combinations = itertools.product(nucleotides, repeat=i)
```

Comment: Don't you wish there was a better name for `combinations` that isn't a related function in the same module? Serious comment though, `product` takes a kwarg `repeat` that should probably be used here.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can generate is using [combinations_with_replacement()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) which allows repetition:

```
import itertools

result=set()
nucleotides = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
for i in range(5,16):
    for j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nucleotides, i):
        print(''.join(j))
```

You can then permute them further to get all variations like this:

```
import itertools

result=set()
nucleotides = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
for i in range(5,16):
    for j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nucleotides, i):
        for k in itertools.permutations(j):
            result.add(''.join(k))
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

To augment Selcuk's answer, here's a one-liner that produces an iterable.

```
from itertools import chain, product

chain(product(nucleotides, repeat=i) for i in range(5, 16))
```